# Probability of a particular event happening after infinite attempts

Tags: probability

I need to ask , how do u calculate the probability of a particular event will happen after infinite attempts ( at least once )

$Q.1$ Suppose I have an event with probabitlty $p$ , what is the probability that it will happen at least once .

$Q. 2$ Suppose I have an event raining .. and the probability that it rains is given by $p(n)$ for nth day .. I need to calculate the event apocalypse . apocalype happens if it rains on all days (:p) . So if I take my time period to be infinity . what is the probability that an apocalypse will happen ( wont say at least once , because if apocalypse happens .. there wont be a second time )

and of course range of $1<=n<=365$ ( no leap years )

eg. For $Q. 2$ let $p(n)=0.5$ for all days . the probability of the event apocalypse also remains $P=0.5$ instead of $P=0.5^{365}$

edit: I don't want it to rain for eternity , I just want it rain for 365 days in one calender year , once in eternity

Comment: As the number of trials approach infinity the "rate of success" approaches the value given by the probability.

Comment: @MattSamuel Didnt get you . Which question did you answer $Q1$ or $Q2$

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho I guess you answered for $Q1$ , u mean that for a dice to get 5 .. the probability of success always remains 1/5 even after infinite attempts ?

Comment: Actually there is no such thing as 'infinite number of attempts'. An infinite process is a "limiting behavior as you approach infinity"

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho , okay that makes sense for $Q 1$ , so what about $Q 2 $ .. I guess it would be different there right ?

Comment: @Aloysius why should there be no such thing as an infinite number of attempts? This is math, not real life.

Comment: @MattSamuel I guess you are right in part. However I think the question "what will happen if you conduct the experiment infinite number of times" is not appropriate with the way we use "infinity" as a limiting process.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the event takes place exactly one time during an infinite sequence of independent experiments is already $1$:

$$P("\text{the number of successes is exactly one}")=p+(1-p)p+(1-p)^2p+\cdots=$$
$$=p\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}=1.$$

The probability that the event takes place *at least* one time is larger or equal than that but smaller or equal than $1$.

As far as raining: The daily raining events are not independent. So, we cannot use this example to enlighten ourserves.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, these questions are about [Tail Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law), which are events defined on a sequence of random variables. The [Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) lemmas are useful here.

Let $E_n$ be the sequence of events in Q1, then Q1 is formally asking for the probability of the tail event $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sup E_n$$

Since the $E_i$ are independent, then by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma:

$$E_i \;\textrm{independent and}\sum P(E_i)=\infty \implies P\left(\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sup E_n\right)=1$$

So the answer to Q1 is 1.

For Q2, let $A_i$ be the event that it rains for $365$ consecutive days starting on day $i$ of the year $i\in 1...365$. Note that all these probabilities are the same: $P(A_i)=P(A_j)=P(A)$. Now, lets define a sequence of events, $E_j\equiv A_{k},\;k=j\mod 365$. What we want to know  is

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i^c\right)\leq P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} E^c_{365i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A^c)$$

The inequality is due to the monotonicity of probability; the equality comes about because the event $E_a$ is independent of $E_{a+365}$

Therefore:

$$P(A^c)<1 \implies P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i^c\right) =0\;\textrm{i.e., Apocalypse almost surely}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability that rains every day for $n$ days is $P = \left(\frac 12\right)^n$

Now if you mean "it has to rain every day of the year", then it is just $\left(\frac 12\right)^{365}$. Note that there is no "infinity" here.

If you mean "it has to rain every day for all eternity", then $n$ is not bounded by $365$ (clearly!) so the probability you're looking for is

$$P = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 12\right)^n = 0$$

---

Probability that in a given year it rains every day:

$$p = \prod_{n=1}^{365} p(n)$$

Probability that in all eternity there is *at least* one year when it rains every day

$$p_{ac1} = \lim_{m \to \infty} 1 - (1-p)^m$$

The probability that it rains at least one year in $m$ years is equal to $1$ minus the probability that it never rains; then take the limit.

Probability that in all eternity there is *only one* year when it rains every day:

$$p_{ac2} = \lim_{m \to \infty} m p (1-p)^{m-1}$$

If $p \neq 0$ (that is to say, for all $n$ we have $p(n) \neq 0$) then you'll find $p_{ac1} = 1$ and $p_{ac2} = 0$

Comment: No , thats not what I asked .. You got the question wrong in couple of ways 1. probability of raining is not 1/2 . 2. I dont want it to rain for eternity I just want it to rain for all 365 days of a calender year once in eternity

Comment: @ShashankGandham can you clarify then? I read your question a couple of times and this is what I understood :-)

Comment: @ShashankGandham you say that in Q2 we have $p(n) = 1/2$. Anyhow you want the probability that there is only one year in all eternity during which it rains every day?

Comment: No .. look i gave an example if $p(n)=0.5$ for all days , but i want in general like what if $p(1)=0.1$ , $p(2)=.5$ .. and random  till $p(365)$ .. I want to understand how this works ... so i want a general explanation .. I want the probability that there is at least one year in whole eternity during which it rains every day

Comment: @ShashankGandham Edited. Did that answer your question?

Comment: Okay .. Now your answer , asnwers my question and sounds logical too ... but can you look at my example .. that seems valid right ? but at the same time doesn't satisfy your equations .. whats wrong in that example?

Comment: @ShashankGandham what example? Can you write a little more clearly? :)

Comment: Look .. if I say that probability for all n p(n)=0.5 .. Now the probability that there is a year in which it rains everyday , isn't it 0.5 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25696/discussion-between-shashank-gandham-and-ant).